# What is the 31st homotopy group of the 2-sphere?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

What is $\pi_{31}(S^2)$, the 31st homotopy group of the 2-sphere ?

---

This question has a physics motivation:

1. There are relations between (2nd and 3rd) Hopf fibrations and (2- and 3-) qubits (quantum bits) entanglement; see [Pinilla and Luthra - Hopf Fibration and Quantum Entanglement in Qubit Systems](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4925v1).
2. Maybe there are relations between classification of qubits entanglements and sphere homotopy groups, and  we are interested in the classification of 4-qubits entanglements.

---

I tried fo find the solution on the net, with help of math [fans](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392293/what-is-pi-31s2/392360#392360), but without success.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres) gives only to the 22nd group homotopy of the 2-sphere.

This article of [John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week264.html) gives interesting references, like [Allen Hatcher, Stable homotopy groups of spheres](http://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/stemfigs/stems.html)  or a link with braids ([Berrick, Cohen, Wong, and Wu - Configurations, braids, and homotopy groups](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-05-00507-2)). One speaks of a book of Kochman Stanley O.: [Stable Homotopy Groups of Spheres: A Computer-Assisted Approach](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0083795).

---

But I am totally unable to find the answer.

A subsidiary question would be: Until what rank do we know these high homotopy group of the 2-sphere?

Comment: In what way the two things you list as motivation are motivation for asking what the 31st homotopy group is?


Comment: In the reference physics article, it is explained that, in a Hopf fibration, the base space (S4,S8) contains information about one qbit, and the entanglement with the others qbits. If there is no entanglement, this reduces to S2. The third Hopf fibration explains 3-qbits entanglement, so it is hoped that sedenions (so S31) could explain 4-qbits entanglement.

Comment: But there is no fourth Hopf fibration!

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is however possible, that there exists a link between this 31th homotopy group of the 2-sphere, and classification of 4-qbits entanglements.

Comment: @David Roberts   : Thanks, have you a reference, please ?

Comment: @David: $\pi_{31}(S^2)$ is well out of the stable range.  There is a homomorphism to the 29th stable group, but it is unlikely to be injective or surjective.

Comment: Ah, how embarrassing.... :-S

Comment: You could deduce some information on $\pi_{32}(S^3)$ from Bob Bruners unstable chart on the bottom of http://math.wayne.edu/~rrb/cohom/index.html (if that's of any help)

Comment: @Christian Nassau : Thanks for the reference (I am going to see it I am able to extract information from this paper) 

Comment: Actually, I remember seeing more unstable charts in the "Oaxtapec proceedings" (CONM146) (Appendix 2 by Paul Shick), but I don't know if this relates to $S^2$. Be warned that it's usually nontrivial to deduce the homotopy from these charts, so this info might not be of much use to you.

Comment: «For separable states, the original Hilbert space $S^7$ simplifies to $S^2\times S^2$» Reading physics papers requires a lot of restraint :-)

Comment: @Mariano : I understand you, but there are also a lot of mathematical books, where the interesting ideas or philosophy are not highlighted, because it is hidden in a too formal or technical presentation. And, in mathematics or physics, the important things are ideas.

Comment: Your link to the article of Berrick, Cohen, Wong, and Wu was broken.  I have changed it to the published version while this is on the front page.

Answer (score 38):

My apologies for updating this very old question.

As already mentioned, the 31st homotopy group of $S^2$ is the same as the 31st homotopy group of $S^3$. Serre's mod-C theory shows that this is a finite abelian group, and moreover that for any prime $p$ the first $p$-primary torsion occurs in $\pi_{2p} S^3$. This means that we don't have to check any primes $p$ for which $2p > 31$, which leaves us with the primes $p=3,5,7,11,13$.

The main tool for calculating these is the EHP spectral sequence. For $S^3$ the EHP sequence is pretty simple: there is a long exact sequence
$$
\dots \to \pi_{n-1}(S^{2p-1}) \to \pi_{n}(S^3) \to \pi_{n}(S^{2p+1}) \to \pi_{n-2}(S^{2p-1}) \to \dots
$$
that goes through $n > 3$.

The next point is the stable range. At odd primes and for odd spheres, the stable range is larger than that given by the Freudenthal theorem: if $n$ is odd, the stabilization map $\pi_{n+k}(S^n) \to \pi_k^S(S^0)$ is an epimorphism if $k=(n+1)(p-1) - 2$ and an isomorphism if $k < (n+1)(p-1)-2$. This means that all the groups relevant to computing $\pi_{31}(S^3)$ appear in the stable ranges of $\pi_*(S^{2p \pm 1})$ for $p \geq 5$, and those stable ranges are moreover very sparse (they only include the "image of J", which is well-known). If I have calculated correctly, $\pi_{31}(S^3)$ includes no $p$-torsion for $p \geq 5$.

That leaves only $p=3$, where we have to switch to a different algorithm ("I cannot do this, so I better look up what Toda calculated"). Toda showed that the 3-primary part of $\pi_{31}(S^3)$ is $\Bbb Z/3$. I found this in his 2003 text, "Unstable 3-primary Homotopy Groups of Spheres", but that was simply because I had it handier.

Combining this with the information from Mark Grant's answer gives $\Bbb Z/3 \oplus \Bbb Z/2 \oplus \Bbb Z/2 \oplus \Bbb Z/2 \oplus \Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: Wow, that's ironic that Toda's text was handy, given how hard it is to find! (I note this answer from 2016: https://mathoverflow.net/a/258475/4177) Here's the link from a comment there in case people are trying to look: https://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110009673506/en

Comment: @DavidRoberts That question from 2016 is more-or-less why I had access to the book in the first place (Professor Minato Yasuo very kindly contacted me and helped me find access to it). These degrees are low enough, however, that I believe this appears in more immediately accessible work of Toda's (possibly "Composition methods...", or several of his papers from the 1960s).

Answer (score 33):

One simple observation is that $\pi_{31}(S^2)\cong\pi_{31}(S^3)$, by the long exact sequence of the Hopf fibration.

The homotopy groups $\pi_i(S^3)$ for $i\le 64$ are apparently computed in:

Curtis, Edward B.,Mahowald, Mark,
*The unstable Adams spectral sequence for $S^3$*,
 Algebraic topology (Evanston, IL, 1988), 125–162, 
Contemp. Math., 96, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1989.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to get a hold of that reference to check for an explicit answer. Maybe someone has it on their shelf and can check.

Comment: The beginning of the article can apparently be read on [Google Books](http://books.google.fr/books?id=vhbzgnjbuRYC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=Curtis,+Edward+B.,Mahowald,+Mark,+The+unstable+Adams+spectral+sequence+for+S3,+Algebraic+topology&source=bl&ots=Goj5ul-qWU&sig=CUtAoL2IEJGpQfLnCPOlVxI9lKo&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=mfiVUbqjIqqG0AXBpoC4BQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Curtis%2C%20Edward%20B.%2CMahowald%2C%20Mark%2C%20The%20unstable%20Adams%20spectral%20sequence%20for%20S3%2C%20Algebraic%20topology&f=false)

Comment: I don't know if it is the correct result, but it seems that the answer should be  
$Z_2 + Z_2  +  Z_2 + Z_2$
(Found page 204, in 1st paper reference below)
**Nobuyuki Oda**, On the 2.Components of the Unstable Homotopy Groups of Spheres I. 
Source: Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci. Volume 53, Number 7 (1977), 215-218.
[1st paper](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.pja/1195517989)


Comment: @Trimok: Good find! Note that this is only supposed to be the $2$_primary part; there may be other summands of the form $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ with $p$ an odd prime.

Comment: @Mark : Yes, I understand this is not the final answer...

Comment: I checked, and unfortunately the reference you've listed only seems to compute the 2-primary part as well.