# Toda's book on homotopy groups of spheres

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

Yesterday one my friend told about recent book of Hiroshi Toda, where the computations of 3-torsion in homotopy groups of spheres are given up to a very high stem (about 75). This book is published with a rare publisher and is overlooked by MathSciNet and ZentralblattMath. Does anybody know the explicit reference: title, publisher, year? 
Thanks. 
Roma Mikhailov.

Comment: https://books.google.nl/books/princeton?hl=en&q=stem&vid=ISBN9780691095868&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=stem&f=false

Comment: @CarloBeenakker this book of 1962 is anything but recent

Comment: https://books.google.nl/books?id=JxCoAAAAIAAJ (1987) --- now if only I could take a peek inside...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I've got the right reference, this appears to be listed as:

- "Unstable 3-primary homotopy groups of spheres, Study of Econoinformatics (Vol. 29), Himeji: Himeji Dokkyo University" in the book "Gottlieb and Whitehead Center Groups of Spheres, Projective and Moore Spaces" by Marek Golasiński and Juno Mukai,
- "Unstable 3-primary homotopy groups of spheres, Econoinformatics 29 (2003)" in the new edition of Ravenel's green book, and
- "Unstable 3-Primary Homotopy Groups of Spheres, Faculty of Econoinformatics, Himeji Dokkyo University, 2003" in Guozhen Wang's thesis proposal.

But I can't find it.

Comment: This appears to be the canonical URL: http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110009673506/en  (no fulltext, unfortunately)